# how to get the data of a document and the collection that this document has?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularjs-directive

I am trying to obtain the data of a document, and also this document has a field that is a collection.
How could I get all that data?
my document has the following properties:

I use angularFire package.

name: string,
lastName: string,
items: Collection.

This document is from a collection users:

Mi code:
collection('users').doc(ID).collection('items').snapshotChanges().subscribe(val =>console.log('val',val), but this return [{type:{},payload:{}},{},....]

I tried changing snapshotChange to ValueChanges, but that only brings me data from my internal collection (items)

Comment: Are you using angular or angularjs? You have both tags and unless you are running a hybrid app you should only have one. If it is a hybrid app then the following question, which side is using angularfire?

Comment: Hi ,post updated

Answer (score 0):

As of now, there is no built-in way of fetching the data of the document and its subcollections in a single query.

One solution would be to make multiple queries, one for fetching the user and another one for fetching his items. Here is one way of doing it using AngularFire:

```
const userDoc = collection('users').doc(ID);
const userItems = userDoc.collection('items').get();
const user = userDoc.get();
```

Now both `user` and `userItems` are Observables of Snapshot.

Depending on what you store in the `items` subcollection, you might want to store `items` as an array on the `users` collection. This way you'll be able to fetch it in a single query on `users`.